# Scanf not working properly with "%c" but works

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char mathoperation;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Give the first number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Give the second number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("Give the math operation you want to use : ");
    scanf("%c",&mathoperation);

    switch (mathoperation)
    {
    case '+':
        printf("%d\n",num1+num2);
        break;
    case '-': 
        printf("%d\n",num1-num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d\n",num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(num2==0)
            printf("No you cant do that");
        else
            printf("%d\n",num1/num2);     
        break;
    case '%':
        printf("%d\n",num1%num2);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error!");
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

When I use "%c" in above code it doesn't take any input and go to `default:` directly
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHmUk.jpg) but if I use `scanf(" %c")` instead of `scanf("%c")` it works
It also works If I use `scanf("%c");` before using `scanf("%d");` it works .
Please help!

Comment: Please use the `scanf(" %c")` you  mentioned, rather than kludges: it is the way `scanf` is intended to be used. The `scanf` conversion stops at the first character it cannot convert, which is typically (but not necessarily) a space or a newline, and that character remains in the input buffer. It will be read by the *next* `scanf()`. Format specifiers `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter leading whitespace characters, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. You can instruct `scanf` to do so by adding a space just before the `%`.

Comment: Thanks, I got that but if I use `scanf("%c")` at start just after declaring the variable then it takes input normally, can you help explaining that ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? There hasn't been any previous input, that would leave a newline in the input buffer.

Comment: I see, understood 
Thanks.